# Do Parallels Plesk Panel 11 have free inbuilt firewall?

Tags: server, plesk, dedicated-hosting

I am new to Linux Dedicated server hosting and plesk panel 11 , i am looking for **inbuilt firewall module** 
.  Is it comes with free in plesk 11 or i need to pay or plesk 11 doesn't support firewall?. I looked at the demo http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/demos/, but i couldn't find any information about firewall in plesk 11.

Comment: For **Windows** it is there: Power User Mode demo -> Server tab -> Tools & Settings -> Tools & Resources -> IP Addresses -> Firewall (button). But it does not work on demo site (for obvious reasons). It uses Windows own firewall, no idea what it will use on Linux hosts.

Comment: @LazyOne you are right i have seen windows demo, firewall option is there , but for linux its not available, Can any plesk 11 linux user can confirm firewall option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, Plesk 11 has free built-in firewall module. You just may not have it installed - if so, go "Tools & Settings > Updates & Upgrades" menu and install missing components.

Comment: In the parallels plesk demo url updates & upgrades link is not working so i am unable to check, can you please confirm are you using plesk inbuilt firewall moduel in production linux server?

Comment: Yes, I have it on Linux